Why is List<Subtype> able to be assigned to List<Supertype> here?
I understand that Java is generally invariant since it does not want to deal with issues of co/contra-variance.
So in general,
List<Parent> a = new ArrayList<Child>();

will require a type-erase-like cast via (List) to make work.
However,
List<Parent> p = Collections.singletonList(<Child>);

works as is, without a cast, despite claiming to return a List<Child> via the documentation.
I experimented a bit and found this is a property of generic returns in general, and is not specific to Collections.singletonList.
There are a couple possibilities here:

it's inferring the return type based on what it is being assigned to

it could, for example, pretend the <Child> parameter is (<Parent>) <Child>, with an implicit cast
a good point to be made is something like Vector<String> s = new Vector<>(); works at least somewhat like this, in terms of inference


it actually just returns List, type-erased, so the List<T> is a misnomer

this makes sense to me, but it's strange that this is an exception case for the compiler and not the first assignment I gave as an example



What exactly is going on here, and why is it okay in this scenario, upon a function return with generics, but not with assignment in general?
Taking this one step further, how does Java implement and special-case this?

"it's inferring the return type based on what it is being assigned to" is exactly what is going here. What do you mean by "how does Java implement and special-case this"? This is not a special case. And do you really want to see the part of the source code of a compiler that implements this?

I'm currently writing a Java compiler for a small (non-generic) subset, so I would actually be quite curious @Sweeper

I'd suggest reading section15.12 and section 18 of the JLS then. The way this is specified there is very close to pseudocode.

Well if you are not implementing generics in your compiler, you don't need to know.  Hint: implementing type inference in a compiler is HARD.


What exactly is going on here

The compiler has determined that T can be type Parent and satisfy the constraints.

why is it okay in this scenario

Because the singleton method take a single value - not a list - and returns a list containing that value.
In this case the value of type Child is a Parent, so the method can return a List<Parent> with that singular child instance.
Think of it as:
List<Parent> p = Collections.singletonList((Parent) child);


You are misconstruing the javadoc.
The notional type returned by singletonList in:
List<Parent> p = Collections.singletonList(<Child>);

is indeed a List<Parent>.  The javadoc should be read as saying that the argument to the method is an instance of T or a subclass of T.  Child is a subclass of Parent.
Basically, type inference has figured out a type for T that satisfies all of the type constraints of the context ... and used it.

Does this have to do with T being in a contra-variant position?
